# Blob store in addition to Cockroachdb

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, blob, cockroachdb

To store blob, what kind of distributed file system should I use in addition to `cockroachdb`?

As I know, with `CockroachDB`, the **max file size is 1MB**.
Should I use `Hadoop`, `HDFS` or something like that, to store files and keep my meta data in `CockroachDB`?

Comment: This is overly broad. At least define the type and approximate size of data you want to store, access patterns, availability requirements, storage overheads, failure recovery, etc... As is, this only invites personal opinions.

Comment: I need to setup a DDB for a website of newspaper articles. I just need to store images/videos in a distributed way, I have several servers located in different places; nothing more.